# What is Nani's gender in Brawl Stars?

Tags: brawl-stars

[image]

> The image’s pronouns are contradictory
> -It says both "*her* friends" and "teleports to *his* last location"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nani is female. The pronouns are not contradictory. The "his" in the description of the Warp Blast gadget refers to Peep.